# Does iOS support vibration?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps, vibration

I'm creating a PWA with JavaScript and shake.js

First I allow DeviceMotion by clicking the button. Then when the phone detects a shake event, it will pick a random item from an array and display it.

I wanted to add a vibration when an item is displayed on the screen as feedback for the user.

I'm testing the app on my iPhone XR in a Chrome browser, but the vibration doesn't seem to work. Does iOS support the vibration API?

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var myShakeEvent = new Shake({
        threshold: 15
    });
    
    const activities = [
        "Watch a movie", 
        "Play cards", 
        "Bake a dessert", 
        "Have a picnic", 
        "Have a photo competition", 
        "Go jog with friends", 
        "Climb a mountain", 
        "Try out a new cuisine you never had before"
    ];

    myShakeEvent.start();

    window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);


    function shakeEventDidOccur() {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length);
        deviceMotion.innerHTML = activities[random];
        deviceMotion.style = "font-size: 20px; margin-top: 20px; color: blue"
        alert.innerHTML = "Shake again for a new activity suggestion!";
        window.navigator.vibrate(200);
    }
}


var deviceMotion = document.getElementById('deviceMotion');
var alert = document.getElementById('alert');

function permission () {
    if ( typeof( DeviceMotionEvent ) !== "undefined" && typeof( DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission ) === "function" ) {
        // (optional) Do something before API request prompt.
        DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
            .then( response => {
            // (optional) Do something after API prompt dismissed.
            if ( response == "granted" ) {
                window.addEventListener( "devicemotion", (e) => {
                })
            }
            deviceMotion.innerHTML = "Shake your phone!"
        })
            .catch( console.error )
    } else {
        alert( "DeviceMotionEvent is not defined" );
    }
}
const btn = document.getElementById( "request" );
btn.addEventListener( "click", permission );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#252A5C">
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="src/styles.css">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/logo192.png">
        <script src="node_modules/shake.js/shake.js"></script>
        <title>Device Motion</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="request">Allow Device Motion Tracking</button><br><br>
        <div id="deviceMotion">Device Motion not allowed yet</div><br><br>
        <div id="alert"></div>
        <script src="src/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using javascript to build your app, you can integrate with capacitor which is pretty good to use native resources. In your case you can use the [Haptics Capacitor Plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/haptics). And it's compatible with iOS

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did: "npm install @capacitor/haptics" and that worked, but 'npx cap sync' I don't understand. Could you explain a bit how to get it to work?

Comment: You use npx cap sync to copy the web app build and Capacitor configuration file into the native platform project, and then updates the native plugins and dependencies referenced in package.json. Note that you just need to use npx cap sync when you're already with a project configurated in iOS or android using capacitor.

Comment: I put this in my main.js after npm installing:

`import { Haptics, ImpactStyle } from '@capacitor/haptics';

const hapticsVibrate = async () => {
    await Haptics.vibrate();
  };`


How do I call the vibrate event in the function shakeEventDidOccur() from above?
The devicemotion permission button also stops working when I add the haptics import.

Comment: How did it work when you use Haptics.vibrate() inside shakeEventDidOccur() ?

Comment: Nothing, because the shake event won't be recognized. The problem I think I have now is that I need to put a line in my index.html to refer to a file from the haptics capacitor plugin. Which file in which folder would that be? `<script src="node_modules/@capacitor/[...]"></script>`

Comment: Now I'm also getting this error on the line of code containing the haptics import. "Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Comment: It is because you're maybe importing on 2 modules, Idk how is your project working. But are you trying to test this on a device ou just on browser? The native components from capacitor/cordova just works on devices.

Comment: I'm testing it on my iPhone (Safari and Chrome) by uploading it to a server from school. I also use a browser on my laptop to see the errors in the console. It's a PWA, so with a service worker, trying to make use of shake.js and capacitor haptics. To active the shake event I have to give permission by pressing a button. Then I can shake the phone and it will display an activity (text). When the text is displayed, the device has to vibrate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243487/discussion-between-jose-lourenco-and-krosral).